# Creating a View with Users From a Specific Role using Entity Framework Application User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Please, I've been struggling with creating a view that would display only users from a particular role.

I have been able to view all users by using the

```
return View(await UserManager.Users.ToListAsync());
```

With the model in my view is `ApplicationUser`

I, however, need just the users from a certain role
I'm using MVC 4.5.1.

Comment: Post some more code of what you have done so far, so we can get a better picture.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the RoleManager :

```
var roleManager = 
   new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

return View(await roleManager.FindByName("Administrator").Users.ToListAsync());
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol - ToListAsync is the error I'm getting

Comment: Also what model would be on the view